# (Angular 6) Dynamically add style to element inside the one that was clicked. Rotate chevron

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I want to rotate chevron when the button is clicked. So my question would be - how to do it? Should I add the whole Angular animation component and do it there or is it possible to just add rotate to just a chevron?

```
<a href="#" (click)="transformArrow()">Show
   <span>
       <label class="m-0">this</label>
       <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-chevron-down" id="myElement"></span>
   </span>
</a>
```

then I tried to add some function

```
transformArrow(){
    let ele = document.getElementById('myElement');
    ele.style.transform  //And I stuck here as I need to actually access ":before" of this element and rotate it.
}
```

---

Huge thanks to trichetriche and malbarmawi for alternative, only thing that I had to change was "after" to "before" :)

My idea is:

```
transformArrow(e) {
    let ele = document.getElementById('myElement');

        ele.classList.toggle('btn-change');


}


.glyphicons-chevron-down
    {
        transition: $trans-1;

        &.btn-change
        {
            &:before
            {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

        }
    }
```

I really like the idea with ngClass but I like to keep most of actions in component.ts so i wanted to stay with function. Is it even good, or maybe it's better practice to do it the way malbarmawi did?

Comment: [Angular Animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations) are designed for this exact purpose, your initial thought was correct. I thoroughly recommend exploring the animations library, it is very nice to use.

Comment: @hevans900 seems a bit overkill for rotating an arrow ...

Comment: Yeah, I thought that it may be a bit too much to add the whole component just to do couple of things on the whole site, so I wanted to avoid it. If the sit is not mostly based on dynamic animation I don't think I would go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngStyle` directive

```
<a href="#" (click)="toggle = !toggle">Show
   <span>
    <label class="m-0">this</label>
    <span [ngStyle]="{'transform': toggle ? 'rotate(180deg)':''}" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
   </span>
</a>
```

another way `ngClass` directive

```
<a href="#" (click)="toggle = !toggle">Show
   <span>
       <label class="m-0">this</label>
       <span [ngClass]="{'flip-h': toggle}" class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></span>
   </span>
</a>
```

or with element reference (**not recommended**)

```
<a href="#" (click)="elem.classList.toggle('flip-h')">Show
   <span>
       <label class="m-0">this</label>
       <span #elem  class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x" id="myElement"></span>
   </span>
</a>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asjcyi)

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it through CSS and custom attributes ?

```js
ele.setAttribute('data-rotate', 'true')
```

```css
span#myElement[data-rotate="true"]:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: (In case that's not obvious, set the attribute to false when you click again)